# Post ID link structure doesn't work with custom post type

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Good day! I first come across of this kind of issue. There is a WordPress site with Custom Post Type UI installed on it. So, only /?P=123 "Simple" link structure works on this project. If I choose for example: site.com/sample-post/ "Post ID" Everything will work fine, except for custom posts. Tell me please how can I solve this issue,Thank

Comment: What's the rewrite option in CPTUI set to?

Comment: There is "true" but it doesn't work right(

Comment: try flushing your permalinks (goto permalinks and click update)